# Using user's current homescreen (w/ icons) in app

Tags: android

I want to use the user's current homescreen as an element of an app, including their icons and layout.  I do not expect it to be dynamic, just a static image of their screen upon which the app can act.  The "Cracked Screen" app does this like I'm thinking.

In researching, I've found ways to grab a screenshot (requires root) or grab the current wallpaper (doesn't include icons), but nothing yet about this particular issue.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the translucent theme. Set it in your AndroidManifest for the relevant activity like this:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" 
     ...>
```

This sets the users homescreen with it's icons as the background of the activity, your views float over that. Alternatively you can use `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` if you want to hide the title bar additionally.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I'm not sure why I didn't find that in my searching, usually my google-fu works better than that.